# Call node function on element hover

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm using ejs template to display articles list and I would like to call a node function with current article as param when hovering user picture

Template

```
<%for (var i=0; i< articles.length; i++){%>
    <div class="ui-block list-article">
        <article class="hentry post video">
            <div class="post__author author vcard inline-items">
                <div id="userProfilImage" class="userProfilImage">
                    <img src="<%= articles[i].user.image %>" alt="author" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
     </div>
<% } %>
```

Nodejs file

```
app.locals.getUserPopupInfo = function(article){
    article.user.name= "blablabla";
}
```

How to call app.locals.getUserPopupInfo function when hovering user image like:

```
<div id="userProfilImage" class="userProfilImage" onmouseenter="getUserPopupInfo(articles[i])">
    <img src="<%= articles[i].user.image %>" alt="author" />
</div>
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I found this:

```
<div id="userProfilImage" class="userProfilImage" onmouseenter="<%= getUserPopupInfo(articles[i]) %>">
    <img src="<%= articles[i].user.image %>" alt="author" />
</div>
```

But It call getUserPopupInfo function on page load. How to prevent this ? I want to call It only on mouse enter

Comment: Ejs injection is called on page load. That the whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to create a REST call, GET in this case to retrieve the data.
You shouldn't call server function from client.

See [nodejs rest tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm)
Or [express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Edit:

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595247/passing-a-function-into-an-ejs-template-for-use-in-an-onclick-event), you need to use client side JS on events handling.

Thus, you have to use server call to retrieve that data.

Comment: I saw in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294515/6002163 that is possible. Can you please give me an example like this ?

Comment: Try to surround the function call with <%%>